# Error Help: Adding to ranges using Application.Union

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to loop through a large list rows searching a specific column for values based on the values in another tab.  I had it working for one value but as soon as I add a second criteria I am receiving errors on the "Set TwoRange = Application.Union(TwoRange, cell.EntireRow)".  I have entered my code below.

Is anyone aware of why I might be receiving these errors?

Edit: The error is "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

```
Sub Calculate()

'----Data Pull----'
  Dim cell As Range
  Dim OneRange As Range
  Dim TwoRange As Range
  Dim ThreeRange As Range
  Dim FourRange As Range
  Dim FiveRange As Range
  Dim SixRange As Range
  Dim SevenRange As Range
  Dim EightRange As Range
  Dim NineRange As Range
  Dim TenRange As Range

  Dim MyCount As Long
  Dim ExistCount As Long
  ExistCount = 0
  MyCount = 1


  For Each cell In Worksheets("Data").Range("C2:C99999")

  If cell.Value = Worksheets("Calculation").Range("B8").Value Then
  ExistCount = ExistCount + 1
      If MyCount = 1 Then Set OneRange = cell.Offset(0, -1)
      Set OneRange = Application.Union(OneRange, cell.EntireRow)
      MyCount = MyCount + 1


  ElseIf cell.Value = Worksheets("Calculation").Range("B9").Value Then
      ExistCount = ExistCount + 1
      If MyCount = 1 Then Set TwoRange = cell.Offset(0, -1)
      Set TwoRange = Application.Union(TwoRange, cell.EntireRow)
      MyCount = MyCount + 1


  End If
  Next cell


  If ExistCount > 0 Then
    OneRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("LOB One").Range("A3")
  End If

  If ExistCount > 0 Then
    TwoRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("LOB Two").Range("A3")
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get the last instance in sheets("data").range('column C') where its equal to each of these criteria and copy the row to a new sheet? If so there is a more efficient way to loop through these

Comment: Also, why offset one column to the left if youre just going to take the whole row anyway? just do `if mycount = 1 then set tworange = cell.entirerow`

Comment: The offset is from a previous version but I will remove it for more efficient code.  Thanks for that!  And the goal is to separate each row into their respective sheets based on the value in column C.  What do you recommend for a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: It's possible that `TwoRange` is still `Nothing` when the problem line runs. You need separate "MyCount" variables for tracking `OneRange` and `TwoRange`.

Comment: Adding a separate count did the trick!  There are going to have to be quite a few variable declarations but it will work.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Tim Williams in the comments.

> It's possible that TwoRange is still Nothing when the problem line runs. You need separate "MyCount" variables for tracking OneRange and TwoRange

Thanks for taking the time to help!